# Background service keeps the app memory

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I have an app with a service in background. The service runs since the boot, but when the app is started, and closed, the service keeps all the memory that the app uses.

How can I clean all that memory for the service to run light like in the boot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop the service, if you are not doing so already (via `stopService()` or `stopSelf()`).

After that, your process will eventually be terminated by the OS, when it needs the RAM for other processes.

Comment: But ti don't want the service to be closed, i need the service running after the app is closed.

Comment: First, that's generally not a good idea. Users really dislike developers that keep services running all of the time. Users will use task killers and the Settings app to get rid of your service. Android will also get rid of your process eventually, despite the service, though not necessarily quickly. In the meantime, your process will use however much memory it needed at its peak. So, either get rid of the everlasting service (e.g., use `AlarmManager` and a polling model) or live with the fact that you are consuming this memory.

Comment: Thanks. The servicien only checks each x hours for a website if it's updated for notify. Can i use AlarmManager for this task?

Comment: @Fischer: Absolutely. That scenario is what `AlarmManager` is for. You would have `AlarmManager` trigger your app to do some work "each x hours". Usually that work would be done by an `IntentService`, which not only gives you a background thread to work with, but it automatically stops itself when the work is done.